# Assign feature array to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model 'Car' that has_many 'features' . I keep all the features in a separate model 'Features'.When a car is created, I want to let the user select (via check-boxes) what features should the new car have.

Right now I'm doing something like this, which is wrong, but I have no other idea :

```
= f.label 'other features'
- Feature.all.each do |feature|
  = f.check_box :feature
```

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- Feature.all.each do |feature|
  = check_box_tag "car[feature_ids][]", feature.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `feature` is an association, you have to use `f.fields_for`, which will yield another formbuilder object. Look for `fields_for` in the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org) to see how to use it properly in your case, I don't have it in mind at the time being. :)

Comment: u r wrong, he don't want to create features,, he want to select them

Comment: I've already created all the features I need, now I only want to append them to the 'features' array of the car

Comment: Oh yup sorry, didn't paid enough attention